# A problem on a linear map from a vector space $V$ to the underlying field $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**The problem**.

Let $T:V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be a linear map. $null\{T\}=\{v \in V : Tv=0_{\mathbb{F}}\}$. Let $u \in V$ such that $u \notin null\{T\}$. To show that $$V=null\{T\} \oplus \{au:a \in \mathbb{F}\}$$

**My approach**.

First let us show that $V \supset null\{T\} \oplus \{au:a \in \mathbb{F}\}$. Since both $null\{T\}$ and $\{au:a \in \mathbb{F}\}$ are subspaces of $V$, the claim follows from the definition of vector space.

Now let us try to show that $V \subset null\{T\} \oplus \{au:a \in \mathbb{F}\}$. I want to show that given $v \in V$, I can decompose it as $v=u_1+u_2$ such that $u_1 \in null\{T\}$ and $u_2 \in \{au:a \in \mathbb{F}\}$. Applying $T$ to both sides and using linearity, we have $Tv=Tu_2$. Since $u_2 \in \{au:a \in \mathbb{F}\}$, $\exists a^* \in F$ such that $u_2=a^*u$. Hence $Tv=T(a^*u)=a^*Tu$. So given $v \in V$, I need to find $a^* \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $Tv=a^*Tu$. If $F=\mathbb{R}$ or any one-dimensional field, sure. But can I always do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that for any $v$, $v - \frac{T(v)}{T(u)}u$ is in $null(T)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is, of course a geometric argumentation or you can also compute explicitly the projectors attached to the direct sum.

Solving, for $y\in V$ and $t\in \mathbb{F}$
$$  
y=x+t.u\ ;\ x\in null(T) 
$$
Then one gets $t=\dfrac{T(y)}{T(u)}$ (note that $T(u)\not=0$).

So the two projectors are 
$$\phi_1(y)= \dfrac{T(y)}{T(u)}.u$$ 
and 
$$\phi_2(y)= y-\dfrac{T(y)}{T(u)}.u$$

Check that these are projectors (only one test is needed) and that they have the correct images.

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful.

Comment: 1) You do not need to "check that these are projectors": you just proved that for every $y\in V$, there is a unique $(x,t)\in\operatorname{null}(T)\times\Bbb F$ such that $y=x+tu,$ which already ended the proof of $V=\operatorname{null}(T)\oplus\Bbb F u.$ 2) Better wording than "Solving, for $y\in V$ and $t\in \mathbb{F}$
$y=x+t.u\ ;\ x\in null(T) 
$": Given $y\in V,$ solving for $(x,t):$ $y=x+tu,\;x\in\operatorname{null}(T),\; t\in\Bbb F.$ 3)  Maybe you should insist explicitely on the uniqueness, while solving this (like the OP did).

Comment: Well, the "need" here is a matter of taste and style (many criteria, often personal :).

Comment: Of course. I just bring knowledge which is IMHO more enlightening like that. This is sterile debate, sorry :)

Comment: Indeed, so I GIVE UP on 1). What do you think of 2) and 3)?